# Do egg whites thin out when salt is added, which will make them easier to mix?

Tags: egg-whites

Does adding salt to eggs cause the white to thin out and increase in size, making it easier to mix?

Answer (score 3):

Salt, sodium chloride, is slightly [chaotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotropic_agent) towards [protein colloids](http://www.jbc.org/content/248/24/8429.full.pdf), so it should loosen up the egg whites slightly by decreasing protein-protein interaction.

That should make the whites easier to mix, but I doubt you'll get a significant size increase out of it.